# GetComponentInParent is not working as expected, returns self instead b

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is an issue about GetComponentInParent method on Unity. I'm using 2021.3.0f1 version of editor.
The thing is, in the below code,

```
playerController = GetComponentInParent<PlayerController>(includeInactive:true);
```

part works fine. But the second line

```
playerCollider = GetComponentInParent<BoxCollider>(includeInactive:true);
```

doesn't return the collider in the parent, but the collider on itself.

Setup of the prefab is like this: There is a parent GameObject, that has a box collider attached to it, and there is another GameObject as a child of it, that also has a box collider, but this one is only trigger. And I'm calling GetComponentInParent method from the child object.

I looked up for solutions to this, and one said to send parameter includeInactive:true but it didn't help either.
Note this, it only occurs when it is called from an instantiated prefab. I tried to call GetComponentInParent method in the Awake method, the result was the same.

Is there a way to solve this without changing the prefab's hierarchy structure?

```
public PlayerController playerController;
public BoxCollider playerCollider;
private void Start()
{
    playerController = GetComponentInParent<PlayerController>(includeInactive:true);
    playerCollider = GetComponentInParent<BoxCollider>(includeInactive:true);
}
```

Comment: Do you get the same result with transform.parent.gameobject.getcomponent ? (Ignore all lower case on a phone not best for writing anything code like)

Comment: since `playerController` and `playerCollider` are public already, just drag-drop the references in Inspector, that even saves you the Performance drop from running many GetComponent Calls in `Start()`. That doesn't answer your question though, so I made this a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: It works this way. But it is very weird it doesn't work the way I told.
I know right, but as I found here:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/763732/getcomponentinparent-how-does-it-work.html
This bug still exists in version 2021.3.0f1, in case anyone else faces the same problem.